# Apply style to textfield under fieldcontainer in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Hi :) I'm defining a `form.Panel` which contains this element :

```
{
            xtype   : 'fieldcontainer',
            layout  : 'hbox',
            anchor  : '100%',
            items   : [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: "this is the label",
                id: 'thisIsTheId',
                name: 'indPartiel'
            }]
        }
```

this

```
{
                xtype   : 'fieldcontainer',
                layout  : 'hbox',
                anchor  : '100%',
                items   : [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: GDR.utils.Resources.getMessage("magasinRetourArticle.indpartiel"),
                    id: 'rma_det_indPartiel',
                    name: 'indPartiel',
                    readOnly:true,
                    hidden:true,
                    flex:1
                }]
            }
```

So it's a `fieldcontainer` which contains a `textfield`.
What i want to so, is to give a new style to my TEXTFIELD and not to my FIELDCONTAINER.
I've found this function :

```
 myComponent.getTargetEl().setStyle('border', '0px !important');
```

But it applies the style to the fieldcontainer and not to the textfield. 
What i'm messing here ? 
thanks in advance for your help guys :)

NB : I didnt apply the style during the creation of the form because the style deponds on other events and it may change.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the style to be applied to `textfield` (that is label, label separator, input element) then you need to grab a reference to it and then:

```
textfield.getEl().setStyle({....});
```

If you want the style to be applied to the input element only then:

```
textfield.setFieldStyle({....});
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the [cls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-cls) config for the textbox and apply the style. 
 for setting it at run time use [setFidlStyle()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-setFieldStyle)

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

The solution is :

```
c.getTargetEl().down('input').setStyle('border', '0px');
```